# Titan lookups on indexed key are incredibly slow?

Tags: gremlin, titan

Using Titan w/ Cassandra v 0.3.1, I created a vertex key index via `createKeyIndex` as described in the [Titan docs](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Blueprints-Interface#graph-indices).

```
gremlin> g.createKeyIndex("my_key", Vertex.class)
==>null
```

I now have appx 50k nodes and 186k edges in the graph, and I'm finding a significant performance difference between lookups using `my_key`.  This query takes about 5 seconds to run:

```
gremlin> g.V.has("my_key", "abc")
==>v[12345]
```

whereas using the index ID takes less than 1 second:

```
gremlin> g.v(12345)
==>v[12345]
```

`my_key` does not have a unique constraint (I don't want to), but I'm wondering what is causing such a discrepancy in performance.  How can I increase performance on lookups for a non-unique, indexed vertex key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is the use of `.has`, which is a filter function and will not use any indexes.  From [GremlinDocs](http://gremlindocs.com/#filter/has):

> It is worth noting that the syntax of `has` is similar to `g.V("name",
>   "marko")`, which has the difference of being a key index lookup and as
>   such will perform faster. In contrast, this line, `g.V.has("name",
>   "marko")`, will iterate over all vertices checking the name property of
>   each vertex for a match and will be significantly slower than the key
>   index approach.

For the example above, this will use the index and perform the lookup very quickly (< 1 second):

```
gremlin> g.V("my_key", "abc")
==>v[12345]
```

Comment: This is not accurate as of Titan 0.5.0: `g.V.has("my_key", "abc")` will now use an available index on the `my_key` key. See Titan's [index docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/indexes.html).